# Pooled read-only SQLite connection is used for read-write access

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, sqlite-net

Used nuget package: System.Data.SQLite.Core, 1.0.98.1

Problem: In my program I use SQLite with enabled pooling and read-only access in some cases. Normally it works fine, but if there is a lot of mixed read-only/read-write intensive requests to database, then program fails with the following exception:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException: attempt to write a readonly database
attempt to write a readonly database
at System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.Reset(SQLiteStatement stmt)
at System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.Step(SQLiteStatement stmt)
at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader.NextResult()
at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader..ctor(SQLiteCommand cmd, CommandBehavior behave)
at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(CommandBehavior behavior)
at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

If I disable pooling, then the program works fine. I assume that somehow pooled read-only connection is used for read-write connection. Do I miss something - i.e. is it expected behavior or not?

Minimum code to reproduce (it fails at INSERT or DELETE). If I introduce delay, for example `Thread.Sleep(10000)`, it works fine. If I remove loop, it also works fine.

```
const string DbFilePath = "test.sqlite";
string readOnlyConnectionString = new SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder
    {
        DataSource = DbFilePath,
        Pooling = true,
        ReadOnly = true
    }.ConnectionString; // data source=test.sqlite;pooling=True;read only=True
string readWriteConnectionString = new SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder
    {
        DataSource = DbFilePath,
        Pooling = true,
        ReadOnly = false
    }.ConnectionString; // data source=test.sqlite;pooling=True;read only=False
File.Delete(DbFilePath);
using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(readWriteConnectionString))
using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand("CREATE TABLE items(id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY)", conn))
{
    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
while (true) // <= if we comment the loop, the program executes without error
{
    using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(readWriteConnectionString))
    using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand("INSERT INTO items(id) VALUES (1)", conn))
    {
        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(readOnlyConnectionString))
    using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM items", conn))
    {
        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    }
    using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(readWriteConnectionString))
    using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand("DELETE FROM items", conn))
    {
        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at those connectionstrings to ensure they are in fact different? Is the file actually writeable on disk at all?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Connection strings are different. File is readable and writeable. As I said, if I disable pooling, or if I introduce artificial delay - the program works fine.

Comment: This looks like a bug, design flaw or perhaps even design decision in the SQLiteConnectionPool class. Judging by a cursory glance at the source ([SQLiteConnectionPool](https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/artifact/aec6733a2d48e3d2)) it seems it only considers the filename, and not the whole connection string.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Thank you for pointing out. Indeed it looks like it cares only about file name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the source code for the [SQLiteConnectionPool](https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/artifact/aec6733a2d48e3d2) class it looks like it only considers the filename when managing pool entries.

Here's a brief excerpt:

```
internal static void Add(
    string fileName,
    SQLiteConnectionHandle handle,
    int version
```

There's no mention of the connection string used, only the filename. As such, using the built-in connection pooling mechanism when you need different connection strings to behave differently and pool separately won't work.

---

Now, "connection pooling" as concept is something the implementor of a ADO.NET class hierarchy decides upon him/herself. The SqlConnection classes pools per unique connection string but this is in no way required by implementations of IDbConnection.

As such, this may just be a design decision made by the creators of System.Data.SQLite. I would, however, send them an email and ask if this was intentional or not.